# Why is my subclass still generic when I supply a type argument to the base class?

Tags: c#, generics

This is something I haven't ever noticed before, but recently ran into.  When I encountered this situation, I was surprised at what the compiler considered was correct, and what it forced me to do.  I think it is easiest described through example.

**Let's say** we have a generic base class with a single method.

```
abstract class GenericBase<T>
{
    public abstract T SomeMethod<T>(T value);
}
```

Nothing crazy here.  Now, let's extend it, providing a concrete implementation for `int`:

```
class IntImplementation : GenericBase<int> // T is now, and forever shall be, int
{
    public override int SomeMethod(int value)
    {
        return ++value;
    }
}
```

Seems simple enough, right?  Or, so I thought... In fact, you **cannot** do this.  The compiler throws you the message

> 'IntImplementation' does not implement inherited abstract member 'GenericBase.SomeMethod(T)'

But... `T` is now an `int`!  Why can't I just substitute this in my override?  It turns out the only *acceptable* override is

```
public override T SomeMethod<T>(T value)
```

which means my method now has to be

```
public override T SomeMethod<T>(T value)
{
    return ++((int)value);
}
```

Wow, that isn't generic at all.  In fact, I might as well ditch generics from the base class and go with good ol' `object`!

Mind.  Blown.  I've been puzzling over what might be the reasoning behind this, but I'm at a loss.  Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: **Nothing crazy here**?  Certainly not!  You've declared two different generic type parameters both called `T`. Please don't do that. You should be getting a compiler warning telling you that this is a bad practice that leads to confusing code.

Comment: I got pwned in an answer and a comment.  This is not fair. :/ Dat generic type argument scope....

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `T` in the generic method has nothing whatsoever to do with the `T` in the containing class, and you should be getting a warning telling you precisely that. **Please read the compiler warnings; they are there for your benefit**.

If you intend for `SomeMethod` to be generic then you should be writing:

```
abstract class GenericBase<T>
{
    public abstract U SomeMethod<U>(U value);
}
```

And now it is clear that `GenericBase<int>` does not affect `SomeMethod<U>` at all.

Or if it is your intention that `SomeMethod` not be genericized at all then *don't genericize it*:

```
abstract class GenericBase<T>
{
    public abstract T SomeMethod(T value);
}
```

And now you can override `SomeMethod` as you describe.

Comment: Wow.  I mean, wow.  I had no idea they were considered completely different parameter types.  Brb, I'm going to go impersonate Vinnie Barbarino for the next hour.  Whoah!  Whoah.  Whoooooah.